# RABBITMQ Communication with C++

Tags: c++, c, rabbitmq, amqp, libuv

I want to send messages to rabbitmq from c++ via libuv, amqp-cpp.

In Windows environment, TCP communication with AMQPCPP seems to be a bit problematic, so I made the code like below.

```
static void alloc_cb(uv_handle_t* handle, size_t size, uv_buf_t* buf) {
  *buf = uv_buf_init((char *)malloc(size), size);
}

void on_close(uv_handle_t* handle)
{
  printf("closed.");
}


void on_write(uv_write_t* req, int status)
{
  if (status) {
    perror("uv_write error ");
    return;
  }
  printf("wrote.\n");
  free(req);
  //uv_close((uv_handle_t*)req->handle, on_close);
}

void on_read(uv_stream_t* tcp, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t* buf)
{
  printf("on_read. %p\n", tcp);
  if (nread >= 0) {
    //printf("read: %s\n", tcp->data);
    printf("read: %s\n", buf->base);
  }
  else {
    //we got an EOF
    uv_close((uv_handle_t*)tcp, on_close);
  }

  //cargo-culted
  free(buf->base);
}

void write2(uv_stream_t* stream, char* data, int len2) {
  uv_buf_t buffer[1];
  buffer[0].base = data;
  buffer[0].len = len2;
  uv_write_t* req = (uv_write_t*)malloc(sizeof(uv_write_t));
  uv_write(req, stream, buffer, 1, on_write);
}


void on_connect(uv_connect_t* connection, int status)
{
  if (status < 0) {
    printf("failed to connect\n"); return;
  }
  printf("connected. %p %d\n", connection, status);

  uv_stream_t* stream = connection->handle;
  free(connection);
  write2(stream, (char*)"test!", 10);
  uv_read_start(stream, alloc_cb, on_read);
}

int main() {
  uv_loop_t* loop = uv_default_loop();

  uv_tcp_t* pSock = (uv_tcp_t*)malloc(sizeof(uv_tcp_t));
  uv_tcp_init(loop, pSock);
  uv_tcp_keepalive(pSock, 1, 60);

  struct sockaddr_in dest;
  uv_ip4_addr("10.10.50.242", 5672, &dest);

  uv_connect_t* pConn = (uv_connect_t *)malloc(sizeof(uv_connect_t));
  printf("allocated %p\n", pConn);

  uv_tcp_connect(pConn, pSock, (const struct sockaddr*)&dest, on_connect);

  uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error in rabbitmq's logs.

```
2023-02-28 15:49:10.901000+09:00 [info] <0.17112.1> accepting AMQP connection <0.17112.1> (ipaddr:51509 -> ipaddr:5672)
2023-02-28 15:49:10.901000+09:00 [error] <0.17112.1> closing AMQP connection <0.17112.1> (ipaddr:51509 -> ipaddr:5672):
2023-02-28 15:49:10.901000+09:00 [error] <0.17112.1> {bad_header,<<116,101,115,116,33,0,0,0>>}
```

I'm new to this, so there's a lot I don't know, but can you shed some light on this?

Comment: This code looks entirely like `C`.  Please tag one language, either C or C++.

Comment: Hello, are these your discussions?

https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP/issues/494

https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/lWcWxbQE4Fc

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wanted to do it in C++ with the AMQP-CPP library, but I couldn't get it right with that library, so for now I'm using my C example with LIBUV as a reference, so I'm writing less of both.

Comment: @LukeBakken Yes, that's right, I read your answer, thankfully, but it didn't resolve the https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP/issues/491 error you posted along with it. Is there any chance you could tell me how to make a tcp connection with libuv after creating a class that inherits from AMQP::ConnectionHandler for that issue?

Comment: https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP/issues/494#issuecomment-1452087879